# Custom CompareEditor with multiple panes

Tags: eclipse, editor, compare, rcp

Eclipse's CompareEditor looks beautiful and has a great functionality.
But, I'm cannot find a simple way to create a custom CompareEditor with multiple panes?

For example:

```
class MultiCompareEditor extends CompareEditor {
  MultiCompareEditor (Object... InputElement)
    {
    }
}
```

After that I'd like to see CompareEditor with number of panes equals to count of InputElements. And it shoud compare neighbours pane in graphics way like normal CompareEditor.
May be completed component exists already?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I'm was on a wrong way, ContentMergeViewer is solution for me.

Comment: Yes, partially, but I was relocated to another project and my colleagues did the rest of my job.